# How to report end of year value of HSA account?

Tags: united-states, taxes, hsa

I need to list the HSA account balance as of December 31, 2017. It would seem to be simple to just retrieve from the 1099-SA as it shows the value of the account on that date. Let's say the account at the end of the year actually had $1,000.

However I have made several contributions for 2017 in 2018 to "catch up", as well as had qualified medical disbursements in 2018. If I added $2,000 to the account would my true end of year account value actually be $3,000 or just the original $1,000?

Comment: Unclear as to where OP is listing end of year account balance. Related IRS page: https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-8889

Comment: Ok so it looks like I include any contributions made for (or on behalf of) 2017 on line 2, and then on line 15 list the amount of qualified medical expenses that were made in 2017. If thats the case then 2018's distributions will be on 2018's taxes?

Comment: Why/where do you need to report your HSA end-of-year value?